# Unable to cause Fragmentation

Tags: contiki

I am using latest build of contiki.

I have just added the following lines [here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp/project-conf.h).

```
#define SICLOWPAN_CONF_FRAG 1
#define UIP_CONF_BROADCAST 1
#define UIP_CONF_REASSEMBLY 1
#define NETSTACK_CONF_WITH_IPV6 1   
#define UIP_CONF_IPV6_REASSEMBLY 1  
#define UIP_CONF_UDP 1
```

I have done no other changes to any of the files.

I want to force fragmentation. Irrespective of whether SICSLOWPAN_CONF_FRAG is enabled, the control reaches [this](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/3f4436bac9a9f6da0df188372d4374693eab8a52/core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c#L1479) line.

I have experimented with various values for [MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/94854177e2837a6dec0e19624887165aa7cec7d5/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp/udp-client.c#L61) but I could not force fragmentation.

I noticed that large packets are not delivered, but are not fragmented.

What is the minimum MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN at which fragmentation should happen?
How do I make fragmentation happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was increasing size of payload but I partially fed data into buffer. As soon as I fed a lot of data in complete buf, the issue was solved.

Credits: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2141